# Salvar conteúdo de uma variavel em um arquivo .txt sem salvar o arquivo apenas permitir o download

Tags: javascript

Teria como pegar os dados de uma variável ex:

`let texto = "Exemplo de Texto"`

e criar um botão que pegasse essa variável e gerasse uma opção de download, em formato txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a classe `Blob`:

```js
function DownloadArquivo() {
  var data = new Blob(["Exemplo de Texto"]);

  var downloadLink = document.getElementById("aDownloadTxt");
  if (downloadLink == null) {
    downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
    downloadLink.setAttribute('download', 'arquivo.txt');
    downloadLink.setAttribute('id', 'aDownloadTxt');
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  }

  downloadLink.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data));
  downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);

  downloadLink.style.display = 'none';
  downloadLink.click();
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="DownloadArquivo()">Download</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Serviu demais, muito obrigado se quiser chamar depois no discord Tux(Gabriel Porfiro)#3634. valeu ai

Comment: Enzo, quando o funcionamento do código é limitado pelas restrições de segurança do snippet é melhor deixa-lo como não executável e fornecer um link para um sandbox onde possa ser executado, informando das limitações aqui da página.